# Difference between two Sorted Arrays

Tags: java

Im trying to create a method that it´s able to print the difference between two sets of numbers

In this case, I want to make the difference (h1 - h2) or in other words, print all the elements of the array h1 that are not also in h2.

so far this is what i have come up with, and it works only if the numbers of the first set h1 are smaller than the ones of the second set h2, but I want to make it work under any given set.

I would really apreciate any idea that you might have, Thanks ¡

```
private void metodoDifference(int[] h1, int[] h2, int m, int n) {
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayDifference = new ArrayList<>();
        while (i < m && j < n) {

            if(h1[i] < h2[j]) {
                arrayDifference .add(h1[j++]);
                i++;}
            else if (h2[j] < h1[i]){
                arrayDifference .add(h1[j++]);     
            }
            else   {
                i++;
                j++;
            }     
            }
            differenceText.setText(arrayDifference .toString());
        }
```

Comment: You only need to record when `h1` is different, so there is nothing to record when `h2` is different.  Also you should only increment the index for the lower value. BTW `h1[j++]` makes no sense. You should only use an index with the same array so swapping array is most likely why your code blows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to need `m` or `n`. I would use [`ArrayList.removeAll(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-). Then, assuming you are using Java 8+, you can collect and box your `int[]`(s) in one step. Like,

```
private void metodoDifference(int[] h1, int[] h2) {
    List<Integer> arrayDifference = Arrays.stream(h1).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    arrayDifference.removeAll(Arrays.stream(h2).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
    differenceText.setText(arrayDifference.toString());
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add some explanation regarding m and n. In the code that I´m creating the user inputs the maximum size of the arrays he wants to work with.  So m would be for the array h1 (h1[m]) and n for the array h2 (h2[n]). So i have to  take that into account for the operations between arrays created by the user.

Comment: what if he also wants to show number in h2 that are not on h1?

Comment: @Graciano I may have (but I don't see how I could have) misinterpreted *print all the elements of the array h1 that are not also in h2.*

Comment: Just tested the option Elliot gave me and it works like a charm, Thanks a lot for the help ¡